# Are there some tips to skip the human check?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, captcha

I'm blind, and I'm Italian too, and yesterday I tried 20 times (more or less) to pass the "human check" to post a question. And what was the result? NOTHING!

So my question is: are there some tips to skip the check?

If the answer is NO, did you think about changing the check to implement logical questions?
Something like:

> How many letters does the word "Paperino" contain?

Or:

> What is the result of: 6 for 3 plus 2 minus 20?

Etc.

*EDIT*: Wow. On this site, the human control doesn't exist! The problem is on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The human control appears only from time to time, you don't get it on every post.

Comment: Have you tried the audio version of the captcha?

Comment: He's blind.  I suspect he *only* uses the audio version.

Comment: Well, I tried obvously the audio challenge...

Comment: emh... sorry for my last comment but the screen reader doesn't love JS (and this site use JS too much), ok I was saying that I have an extension for Firefox (webvisum) and it should traslate the capcha challenge but in this site it doesn't work! Uff...

Comment: Webvisum now works properly! My suggestion still remanins!

Comment: The human check is fairly rare, however I get it on UX.stackexchange a couple times a week. I'd say I get it once a few dozen posts. This still sounds like a significant accessibility issue however and I don't know if/how our captcha program handles accesability

Answer (score 3):

We use Recaptcha standard, same as millions of other websites. Recaptcha has audio for blind users, it's the little audio icon. See for yourself at

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha

Per the (Google owned) service itself, as stated [on the home page](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

> - Strong security
> - **Accessible to blind users**
> - 30 million served daily

It sounds like per your comment, this was an issue with a browser extension.